# Calculations in form with percent formated box

Tags: vba, excel

I have some TextBoxes programed to show results of calculations based on cost, quantities and taxes. The problem is, if I program the tax box to be formatted as percent on exit, the calculation no longer occurs after the action, because the box becomes string typed. Is that a normal behavior? Is there a way to solve that? Currency formatted TextBoxes bring normal calculation results. The problem is a percent issue only...

[image: Form print with visual explanation]

PS.: I use the common formatting method:

```
Private Sub BoxIPI_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    BoxIPI = Format(BoxIPI, "percent")

End Sub
```

The code is long because of the quantity of calculations needed, but, to put it on a nutshell, I united the parts that calculate de IPI, as an example (the variables are public):

```
If IsNumeric(.BoxQtd.Text) = True Then
Quantidade = .BoxQtd
Else: Quantidade = 0
End If

If IsNumeric(.BoxVendaU.Text) = True Then
VendaUni = .BoxVendaU
Else: VendaUni = 0
End If

If IsNumeric(.BoxIPI.Text) = True Then
IPI = CDbl(.BoxIPI)
Else: IPI = 0
End If

VIPI = (Quantidade * VendaUni) * IPI
.BoxValorIPI = Format(VIPI, "currency")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code I have decided to whip a cool example for you to see how to deal with your issue.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If InStr(TextBox1.Value, "%") > 0 Then
        myValue1 = Mid(TextBox1.Value, 1, InStr(TextBox1.Value, "%") - 1)
        myValue1 = myValue1 / 100
    End If

    myValue2 = TextBox2.Value

    myValue3 = myValue1 * myValue2

    TextBox3.Value = myValue3

    Debug.Print "v1 "; myValue1
    Debug.Print "v2 "; myValue2
    Debug.Print "v3 "; myValue3

End Sub
```

The issue youre having with your code is

```
If IsNumeric(.BoxIPI.Text) = True Then
   IPI = CDbl(.BoxIPI)
Else: IPI = 0
End If
```

The % sign makes the compiler think that BoxIPI.Value is not numeric. Using this will solve your issue

```
If IsNumeric(Mid(TextBox1.Value, 1, InStr(TextBox1.Value, "%") - 1)) Then
    myValue1 = Mid(TextBox1.Value, 1, InStr(TextBox1.Value, "%") - 1)
    myValue1 = myValue1 / 100
End If
```

Of course you dont need to use my decimal division as you can just adapt this to your cause and of course change "TextBox1" to BoxIPI, but you get the point :)

Comment: Hi, Doug! Thanks for your help! I have updated my question with an example of the code I use. I have to define variables this way because I need the calculations to happen in real time as any of the TextBoxes change, and it prevents errors from happening in case of a user typing text or symbols. Is it possible to embed your solution on my code?

Comment: @AlekosMazzolotti I have updated my answer to explain it in more detail and show you what part you can use